# embedded fixed dynamic video as background with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, video

I'm attempting to create an embedded dynamic video background using HTML and CSS (no PHP and no JQuery). The background must fit the full width and height of the viewport. I was able to create the dynamic video but now I'm having difficulties with making it a fixed background. When I change `position` to `fixed`, the video isn't fullscreen. I've looked through countless tutorials, but was not able to find what I'm looking for. Here's what I have so far:

**CSS**

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-container">
         <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFVxGRekRSg" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick for you?

```
 <style>
    .video-container{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index: -55;
    }
    #test{
        color:white;
        width:220px;
        margin:300px auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe style="border: none" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFVxGRekRSg" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"  allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
<div>
    <h2 id="test">Other content</h2>
</div>
```